# computing large roots : bigdecimal / java

Tags: java, root, bigdecimal

I tried to use the standard iterative algorithm to compute nth roots.

For instance (111^123)^(1/123).

The standard algorithm computes high powers <strike>of the base (in this case 111^123)</strike> which takes a lot of time. The algorithm is given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm

However, I noticed that the same thing using double takes less than a millisecond. So obviously they use some smart ideas. Any hints on this?

Comment: anyone has any bright ideas?
I tried the following. For computing `a^(1/x)` for large `a, x` with `x` integer, 
I computed a random `b` such that `b^x < a` but `b^(x+1)>a`. Let `c=a/b^x`. I computed `a^(1/x) = (a*b^x/(b^x))^(1/x) = c^(1/x)*b`. 

I was hoping that by keeping the base `c` small, I could gain some time.
Unfortunately, I either get divide by zero error in computation of `c^(1/x)` if I keep the scale of the division small, or long computation time if I keep this scale big. So this does not buy anything.

Comment: I get some improvement (from hours to minutes) by making b smaller.

That is, `b^x<a < b^(x+sqrt(x))`. The time of several minutes is still not short enough.

Answer (score 4):

> However, I noticed that the same thing
>   using double takes less than a
>   millisecond. So obviously they use
>   some smart ideas.

Not really. `double` simply has limited precision, so it basically only has to compute the most significant 52 bits of the result and can skip the rest of the calculation. And of course, having this implemented in hardware also helps.

Comment: Yes, the limited precision is probably what makes `double` fast. I should have figured that out myself :-)

What I really need is a clever algorithm to keep precision and compute large roots quickly. But... I'm sure this has been done in the literature, so I'm looking for references.

Answer (score -1):

Try using binary exponentiation. What I mean is do:

111 * 111 = 111^2, now you know what 111^2 is, you can now calculate 111^4 by doing (111^2) * (111^2). Here is the whole sequence (Note that this is probably not the most efficient way).

```
111 * 111 = 111^2
111^2 * 111^2 = 111^4
111^4 * 111^4 = 111^8
111^8 * 111^8 = 111^16
111^16 * 111^16 = 111^32
111^32 * 111^32 = 111^64
111^64 * 111^32 = 111^96
111^96 * 111^16 = 111^112
111^112 * 111^8 = 111^120
111^120 * 111^2 * 111^1 = 111^123.
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that if that really optimises anything, it'd have been built-into the class. Generally, prefer to do the simplest thing that works.

Comment: I thought poster might've been creating his own implementation or something.

Comment: the problem is not in computing 111^123
but in computing (111^123)^(1/123)

let `a = 111^123` then to compute `a^(1/123)`, the standard algorithm must compute a^122 and all powers below that.

This is a problem because (111^123)^122 is a very large number.


Note that the BigDecimal class does not implement the root function.

Comment: Use the same method, but using square roots.

Comment: Well I really don't want to compute 111^123^122.. since either way the number is too large and will take memory and time. I need an alternative method to compute roots that doesn't first compute powers

Comment: How much accuracy do you need?